# Functions to aggregate with pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

I didn't find on the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) which functions I can use on the aggregation.

The basic ones are know as 'min', 'max', 'count' but I didn't find anywhere that I could use 'nunique' for distinct count.

Is there a list of available functions anywhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/api.html#groupby shows all of the function calls that can be applied on groupby's that are pre-defined for you.

Comment: Have you tried using it `nunique` should work just fine.